# Identify the author of a story in a high school textbook called "Ask Minnie"

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

In the early 1980s, my wife read a story during a science fiction "mini-course" in high school, titled "Ask Minnie" - which she describes as "like *With Folded Hands*, but awful." I'd like to be able to tell her the author's name, if I can.

Comment: I can't see any obvious matches; https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/se.cgi?arg=Minnie&type=Fiction+Titles

Comment: https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/se.cgi?arg=Ask&type=Fiction+Titles

Comment: Sadly isfdb is weak on fiction published in textbooks

Comment: So the story was about overly paternalistic robots, who take away mankind's reason to live?

Comment: A minnie-course

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Ask Minnie" was written by Juliana O. Muehrcke.

It appears in the 1978 edition of *Be a Better Reader: Level F* which can be borrowed from the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/bebetterreaderle0000smit).

Here is the introduction to the story:

> More and more things that used to be done by people are now being done
> by machines. They wash our clothes and dishes, do our arithmatic -
> they can even help us choose a person to marry. In the future,
> machines will be able to do even more. Do you think that will be good
> or bad? Don't decide until you read this story. Of course, if you have
> trouble making up your mind, you can always... Ask Minnie

Comment: Thank you so much